# How to filter by a date range in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter

I am migrating a solution from SP2013 to SP Online.  I have a library of documents with start and end date for when they were applicable.  I need a way for the user to enter a date range, and then return all documents that overlap with this range at all.

In on-prem SharePoint, I used two date filter web parts to set two parameters and then filtered by these parameters (all using SharePoint Designer).  But not seeing how I might do something similar with SP Online.  It does not appear to have data filter web parts (or anything analogous).  At the moment I am hating SP Online (everything is different!)  Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: In Modern experience you need to use the SharePoint default filters on column headers in library view. In classic experience you can use **metadata navigation** settings of document library for filtering on specific fields (you can also use connected webparts).

Answer (score 0):

1. In the classic SharePoint library, you could insert date filter web part.
   [image]
2. In the modern SharePoint library, you could use filter.
   [image]
3. Modify the current view, set filter.
   [image]